# Python Modules for Anova

Tags: python, anova

I am looking for a Python module that will replicate the features in this JMP plot. It is like a multi variable boxplot but the quartiles are represented with lines, the raw data points are shown, and there is an adjoined box with circles representing the test statistic. P-levels would be a bonus. I would be fine with a Tukey-Kramer, t-test or anything else that serves the purpose.

Any suggestions?

[image]